Wildcard(*) in destination directory for batch MOVE file
I am attempting to move a file to a directory with a "*" wildcard in name with below code:
@ECHO OFF

:: Define variables with quotes to handle spaces
SET "Evidence_File=%~dp0TEST*.txt"
SET "Evidence_Dir=%~dp0Archive*\"

:: Echo the file and folder paths for debugging
ECHO %Evidence_File%
ECHO %Evidence_Dir%

:: Move files matching the pattern to the specified directory
FOR %%F IN (%Evidence_File%) DO (
    MOVE "%%F" "%Evidence_Dir%"
)

PAUSE

I am seeing the below error, and file is not moved.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.


Folders in Windows aren't allowed to have * in their name. I don't know how you created this directory, but you should use that same technique to rename the folder.

The folder doesn't actually have a star in it's name, it is named "Archive1" or "Archive_yay" or something else, I don't know what it is called, hence why I am attempting to use a wildcard (*) in the folder name,

You can't use wildcards in pathnames for move.

My first advice is to remove the trailing backward slash from your wildcard directory name. (Directories do not contain that character; it is a path separator, and you are not separating anything). Now try using another For loop to retrieve the name of your wildcard directory.

The wildcards * and ? are allowed only in last part of a file/folder name or wildcard pattern string after last directory separator \. A FOR /D loop can be used to get the name of a non-hidden folder using a wildcard pattern.
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

REM Define variables with quotes to handle spaces, ampersands, etc.
SET "Evidence_File=%~dp0TEST*.txt"
FOR /D %%I IN ("%~dp0Archive*") do SET "Evidence_Dir=%%I" & GOTO MoveFiles
MD "%~dp0Archive_1" 2>NUL
IF EXIST "%~dp0Archive_1\" set "Evidence_Dir=%~dp0Archive_1" & goto MoveFiles
ECHO Failed to create directory: "%~dp0Archive_1"& PAUSE & EXIT /B 1

:MoveFiles
REM Echo the file and folder paths for debugging.
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO !Evidence_File!
ECHO !Evidence_Dir!
ENDLOCAL

REM Move files matching the pattern to the specified directory.
MOVE "%Evidence_File%" "%Evidence_Dir%\"
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE

Directory and file names and wildcard patterns without or with path should be always enclosed in ", especially on parts are variable like batch file directory path referenced here with %~dp0 which can be expanded to C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!). It is therefore recommended making sure that command extensions are enabled and delayed variable expansion is disabled before using the command SET with %~dp0. The second command line with SETLOCAL defines the required execution environment for the batch file.
The debug output of the strings assigned to the environment variables Evidence_File and Evidence_Dir without surrounding " works only safe for all possible batch file directory names if using delayed variable expansion.
The command MOVE supports wildcard patterns in the first argument string (source specification). A FOR loop is not necessary in general for moving multiple files matching a pattern to a specific directory.
This batch file was tested with C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!)\MoveFiles.cmd with the directory C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!) containing the following files and folders:

Archive_20
Test File 1.txt
Test File 2.txt

The output on execution was:
C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!)\TEST*.txt
C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!)\Archive 20
C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!)\Test File 1.txt
C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!)\Test File 2.txt
        2 file(s) moved.
Press any key to continue . . .

The result of the batch file execution was:

Archive_20

Test File 1.txt
Test File 2.txt



To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

echo /?
endlocal /?
exit /?
for /?
if /?
md /?
move /?
pause /?
rem /?
set /?
setlocal /?

See also:

How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?
Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?
Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file
The general issue chapters in this answer.

